# Rigging problem with a Telescope

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, groups

I have modeled a telescope and I want to rig it to rotate and pan it as needed in the final scene.
I have grouped the parts that I want to rotate and pan seperately, added two bones for both the actions and then parented the groups to bones. Now the problem is that the telescope contains some parts which rotate and the same parts + some other which pan it around but I can only parent an object to one bone. So how would you rig it to create both movements?
[image: Panning]
[image: Rotating]

Edit: Also, I would like to constrain the Rotation of panning to Global Z axis and Rotation to Global Y axis.

Edit: This is what I want.

Rotating:
[image: Rotate]

Panning:
[image: Panning]

Comment: The rotation bone have to be the child of the panning bone.

Comment: could you please show a simple drawing of what are the possibilities of your telescope?

Comment: I have added the GIFs. Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To commincate the problem better I will concentrate on this simplified representation.

[image: setup]

I will refer to the blue object as the **Yaw**, which will rotate around the Z axis and to the red object as the **Pitch** which will rotate around the X axis.
When rotating the Yaw object, the Pitch object should follow as if it was connected. When rotating the Pitch object, the Yaw object will be unaffected.

Add two bone at the position, where the rotations should occur. Parent the Pitch bone to the Yaw bone, this way it moves as a child when rotating the Yaw bone.

[image: bone locations]

Add a control bone. The user will only interact with this single bone, we can hide the other bones later. Position and scale it at convenient values, so that we can easily grab and manipulate later. Lock its Z axis, and set its rotation order to **ZXY**.

[image: control bone]

Add a **Copy Rotation** constraint to the Yaw bone. Select the *ControlBone* as the target bone. Choose **Local** space for both inputs. Finally, make sure only the **Y** option is checked, since we only want the bone to copy the rotation for it's local Y. (If we had oriented the bone differently than shown in the second image, this option would have to be selected accordingly.)

[image: constraint settings]

Add the same constraint for the Pitch bone. Use the same settings except for the axis. Only select the **X** axis for this bone.

As a result, when you select the control bone and rotate it in the viewport, the constrained bones will only copy the rotations which we selected. The telescopes orientation can be controled with a single bone now.

[image: result]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed. Actually I am still a beginner at rigging. I am facing a minor problem. The pitch and yaw bones work perfectly fine in object mode but they do not move the mesh in pose mode; And the control bone does not work in object mode and it only affects the pitch and yaw bones in pose mode and not the mesh. Take a look at [this](https://imgur.com/IavSw8D) and [this](https://imgur.com/2s8cKYm)

Comment: Have you downloaded my file and examined it? Can you infer the setup from it please. In your inages, you have created three separate armatures and parent the objects to the armature, instead of the pose bones. I would recommend following some beginners rigging tutorials to get the basic concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a rig and bones at all, a telescope is is a hard object, you can use parenting and constraints, then use the transforms to do any animation of it you need. There isn't a need to use bones at all for it.

Comment: I tried creating empties and parenting the parts to empties but the same problem occurs. I cannot parent an object to multiple empties which I need to since the telescope contains some parts which rotate and the same parts + some other which pan it around. I've also added GIFs to the original question for explaining what I exactly want. Thanks.

Comment: This is the best answer. What is shown in the GIFs can be controlled with a simple hierarchical structure - parenting is enough and you don't need empties or bones, unless you want to have them for your own satisfaction alone. You can set the origins of 2 parts to be where the pivots you need are and parent everything else to them. If one is parented to another it will inherit rotation from parent and have rotation of its own and that's the 2 parameters to animate, there is really no need to add so much complexity here for such a simple thing. No need to make it difficult without reason.

Comment: I agree.. bones are unnecessary.